# Android activity rotation locked in manifest, but need to grab the orientation event

Tags: android, android-activity, camera, orientation

I am designing a application that uses the camera. I want it locked it landscape mode and just have the pictures(for example, a handle to change between camera and video) rotate. I don't want to launch `onCreate()` again. This is so the camera/video logo does not appear sideways on the screen.

I have put this in the manifest:

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

This keeps the screen from turning. However, I can't seem to figure out how I get the event that tells me when turn the images. I have seen camera apps do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've locked your activity using manifest, the only workable solution to track orientation I saw was using [`OrientationEventListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationEventListener.html).

You'll need to convert degrees to correct orientation yourself. But that is relatively easy task.